# Remove double title in appendix in Latex

Tags: appendix

My main.tex contains the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}

\include{i10preamble}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendix}
\include{appendix_01}
\emptydoublepage
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

And my appendix_o1.tex file starts with:

```
%!TEX root = ./main.tex

\chapter{Appendix A}
\label{app.01}
```

However, when I compile it, the title "Appendix A" is repeated twice.
[image]

Do you have an idea on how I can remove one title and keep only one?
I tried deleting/replacing \chapter{Appendix A} but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: you have given no information about your input. `appendix` and `\chapter` are not defined in latex itself but by the document class you are using, so without a small complete example showing the problem it is very hard to help.

Comment: In the `book` class, for example, when `\appendix` is invoked, "Chapter" is redefine to be "Appendix", the counter is reset to 1, and presented as `\Alpha`, so simply entering `\chapter` will produce "Appendix A".  By entering `\title` with that same text, you are producing the repeated text yourself.

Comment: Hi Barbara, thank you for the explanation. I am still a little bit confused. How can I counter this? Sorry for my naive question, I am not an advanced user of Latex

Answer (score 1):

The first "Appendix" of your example belongs to the appendix numbering. The second is the title.

If you don't want to show the first use

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{}%
```

Alphs numbers A, B .. are needed and will remain.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}  

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{}% supress appendix name <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First Chapter}
    
    \begin{appendix}    
    \chapter{This is Appendix A}    
    Appendix A here.
    \chapter{This is Appendix  B}   
    Appendix B here.    
   \end{appendix}       

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It is working!

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this as a comment bot for some reason SE does not allow me to do that. This is an extended version of @barbarabeeton's comment which you did not appear to understand, showing what she meant.

```
% appprob.tex   SE 625868

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}

\include{i10preamble}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendix}
\chapter{} % no chapter title
\label{app.01}
\end{appendix}

The appendix is \ref{app.01}

\end{document}
```